# Some pointers on constructing a proposal density in a Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm for Gaussian Processes

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

I have a likelihood similar to a Normal density. I'm thinking of using matrix-valued covariance function a $\sum^Q_{q=1}A_q \otimes k(X,X)$, where $k$ is a Matérn class covariance function.
The other parameters I'm thinking of giving them uniform, normal, beta, gamma, and inverse-gamma priors.

I'm looking for general pointers on constructing a proposal density in a Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm for Gaussian Processes.

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more detail than that if you want any but the most generic help possible!

Comment: @jbowman I've edited the question. Can you vote to reopen it ? ;)